# Handle Toast Notification in Windows Phone 8 using Mvvmcross-platform

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, mvvmcross, toast

We're developing an application which is receive toast notification when app is not active.
But it's seem like Mvvmcross Core have taken control of the application and control the RootFrame. So when a toast notifcation comming, user click in that toast and the application doesn't launch exactly to the uri was set in the push, it launched to page that was set in Core when App Start.

I would ask if there's anything solution for this case ? 
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is covered by "Custom app starts" - it's covered for WP in https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/appstart-in-mvvmcross - there's also some information about custom AppStart in the wiki on http://github.com/mvvmcross/mvvmcross/wiki